# Generic method overloading and precedence

Tags: c#, generics, overload-resolution

I have two overloaded generic methods:

```
T Foo<T>(T t) { Console.WriteLine("T"); return t; }

T Foo<T>(int i) { Console.WriteLine("int"); return default(T); }
```

When I try to call `Foo` as follows on my computer:

```
Foo(5);
```

I get no compiler errors or warnings, and the *first* method with the generic argument is called (i.e. the output is `T`). **Will this be the case in all C# incarnations and on all platforms? In that case, why?**

On the other hand, if I explicitly specify the type in the generic call:

```
Foo<int>(5);
```

the *second* method with the `int` argument is called, i.e. the output is now `int`. **Why?**

I am using different argument names in my two method overloads, so the output from the following calls are as expected:

```
Foo<int>(t: 5);       // output 'T'
Foo<int>(i: 5);       // output 'int'
```

If I am calling the first method, I can even leave out the type specification:

```
Foo(t: 5);            // output 'T'
```

But if I try to compile this:

```
Foo(i: 5);
```

I get an error *The type arguments for method 'Foo(int)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.* **Why cannot the compiler deal with this call?**

*Note* These tests have been performed with *LinqPad* on a Windows 8 x64 system (in case that is relevant to the results...)

Comment: Note to answerers: There are _four_ questions buried here

Comment: @SLaks Sorry for the multi-question, but I think these things tie together. If necessary I can split the question. And the default parameter was irrelevant to the question, so I have now removed it from the code.

Comment: +1 Very good question.  I'm not sure.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to spend a bit of time reading through the section of the specs related to method overload resolution.  The short answer is that this is simply the way the specs/compiler were written to function...

Comment: @Servy: yes, I probably need to... But the invocations seems counter-intuitive to me in this case. I read on SO (with a ref to the language spec) that the most specialized method takes precedence; if my second method would have had the signature `int Foo(int i)` instead, *this* method would have been invoked by the `Foo(5)` call. Why is this no longer true when I create a generic method with the same argument signature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Last question

Since you specified (by parameter name) that it should call the overload that takes an `int` parameter, the compiler has no idea what to pass for `T`.

### First question

Because of this, `Foo(5)` *only matches one overload* (`Foo<T>()`).
Therefore, it must only call `Foo<T>()`.

### Second question

When you explicitly specify a type argument (`<int>`), both overloads are applicable.
In that case, `Foo(int)` is better, since its parameter is not of generic type.

As per the C# spec §7.5.3.2:

> - Otherwise, if MP has more specific parameter types than MQ, then MP is better than MQ. Let {R1, R2, …, RN} and {S1, S2, …, SN} represent the uninstantiated and unexpanded parameter types of MP and MQ. MP’s parameter types are more specific than MQ’s if, for each parameter, RX is not less specific than SX, and, for at least one parameter, RX is more specific than SX:
>
>   - **A type parameter is less specific than a non-type parameter.**

(emphasis added)

Comment: @AndersGustafsson: I answered the other two questions.

Comment: Great explanation, @SLaks! It is all so clear now :-) Many thanks!

Comment: @AndersGustafsson: The key point (which I can't find explicitly in the spec) is that methods with non-inferrable type parameters are not candidates for overload resolution.  Had that not been true, `Foo(5)` would have given the same "Cannot infer arguments" error, since `Foo<?>(int)` would then have been the better choice.

Comment: @SLaks: Nice answer. The line of the spec you are looking for is "if F is generic and M has no type argument list, F is a candidate when type inference succeeds..." in section 7.6.5.1.

Comment: @EricLippert: Thanks.  I knew there had to be a line like that somewhere; I just couldn't find it.